# Saltar firewall con XMPP Http-Bind

Tags: xmpp, firewall, ejabberd

Hola se que se puede hacer un XMPP con puertos 80 o 443 para ello hay servicios como puede ser jwchat y por medio de una web se hace la configuración para utilizar el puerto 80. Necesito documentación o alguien que sepa al respecto. Graciass

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar XMPP sobre BOSH http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html

Básicamente es un long polling sobre http o https, lo soportan la mayoria de librerias entre ellas Strophe.js.

Lo he utilizado con Ejabberd como servidor y Strophe en cliente sin problemas.

**Update:**

Básicamente ejabberd estará escuchando por el 5280, necesitarás un nginx o parecido para hacer un rewrite del /http-bind al host:5280/http-bind. Luego simplemente dile a strophe (o lo que utilices) que apunte a host/http-bind. Aquí tienes una configuración de ejemplo para nginx y ejabberd: http://anders.conbere.org/2011/05/03/get_xmpp_-_bosh_working_with_ejabberd_firefox_and_strophe.html

Con el strophe

```
var connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://host/http-bind');
connection.connect('domain/pubsub','', function(status){
  switch(status){
     case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
         console.log('connected');
         connection.subscribe('key', [], function(event){
             console.log($(event).find('entry').text());
         });
         break;
     case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED:
         console.log('disconnected');
  }
});
```

Comment: ok pero la configuración que es coger un servidor jabber que soporte http bind y luego? que debo hacer?

Comment: Utilizar una librería de cliente como Strophe.js https://github.com/strophe/strophejs para conectar, subscribirse, enviar y recibir mensajes.